# What's the -2σ quantile?

Tags: quantiles

I'm researching about direct detection of Dark Matter and came across the -2σ quantile in this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.111302. (Page three at the bottom.)

Now, I know that a 2σ quantile is where about 95% of all events are supposed to be. But what is the -2σ quantile? I've read somewhere that it's 25%, and I feel like I searched the entire internet for that, but I can find anywhere where this is written. So I wanted to make sure I got that right.

And if that's so, does that mean they defined this reference region between the median of anticipated Dark Matter events and the position in that signal space where 25% of all events are thought to be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20Chebyshev's%20inequality,certain%20distance%20from%20the%20mean.)

Comment: Isn't that the 0.025 percentile? i.e. it's just the $2\sigma$ percentile but only for the lower tail?

Comment: The naming convention used in the paper is rather unorthodox, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile . Keep in mind that the $2\sigma$ range covering 95% of the population assumes a normal distribution, it's not universal property.